# Alt + Up Scrolls Screen as it Moves Lines Up

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> quite a lot in Visual Studio to move lines up or down. When I upgraded to Visual Studio 2017, I noticed that when I do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> it moves the line but ***the screen scrolls as well***. This is rather annoying and I think it has to do with CodeLens. I am using ReSharper, but otherwise have a very vanilla installation of Visual Studio 2017. Has anyone else experienced this issue or know of a fix?

**Breakthrough:**

I now know it is CodeLens. When I disable CodeLens, it doesn't happen at all. Is there no way to fix this?

**This is What is Happening**

[image]

Here I am typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> over and over. ***I just want it to move the line not scroll.***

Comment: What happens if you (temporarily) disable ReSharper?

Comment: Yeah, it still happens when I disable ReSharper. It doesn't scroll if I disable the Alt + Up key binding. So it's not some separate key binding. I kinda think it has something to do with codelens.

Comment: Hmm, not CodeLens.  Use Tools > Options > Customize > Keyboard.  Navigate to "Press shortcut keys" and type Alt+Up.  The "currently used" combobox list all of the commands bound to the keystroke.  It is a big list, only the editor commands are relevant.  It is Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp on my machine, so does what you prefer.

Comment: I know this. That is not my problem at all. Please read the post.

Comment: I am experiencing the same behavior in visual studio enterprise 2017. Pressing CTRL+Z after alt up or alt down also scrolls the screen. This only seems to happen in files with less than 30 or so lines, but I can't pinpoint it further than that.

Under Options > Environment > Keyboard I only see Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp, there is nothing there about scrolling.

Turning off codelens is a temporary workaround.

Comment: This has just started happening to me now. I don't think I've even updated Visual Studio 2017 recently. But restarting Visual Studio has stopped it happening for now...

Comment: @AdamGoodwin, Do you have CodeLens anotations? Because I am convinced that is what is causing it for me.

Comment: I do, but I have had CodeLens for years and I only just started having the problem a few days ago. I'm not saying CodeLens isn't the problem, but it doesn't seem to simply be that CodeLens always means you have this problem. (The problem has started again by the way, so restarting VS wasn't a very permanent fix.)

Comment: @AdamGoodwin, All I know, is that when I turn the CodeLens annotations off, the problem goes away. By annotations, I mean the links above the classes and member declarations in the editor.

Comment: Yeah, I understood. I will turn off those if I have to, but I like using them - especially for the references one. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue: if you're still affected, please upvote this bug on the VS developer community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/519058/altup-causes-editor-window-to-scroll.html

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Visual Studio version 16.7 after enough [pushing from the developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/519058/altup-causes-editor-window-to-scroll.html).

If you have this issue and are on an older version of Visual Studio, upgrade to 16.7.

Comment: My company has to pay for it, but we will upgrade when we can.

Answer (score 0):

I am using KDE Plasma version 5.23.4 / Frameworks 5.89.0 for VS Code on Arch Linux 2021-12-18, which I like infinitely better than Windows for the development I'm doing, but the difference in keyboard shortcuts were really getting to me.  I had managed to "fix" them all manually to behave like I had become accustomed to in Windows *except* **alt+up** for moving the entire line up in the editor, *and it was becoming very irritating*.  It took me a while to figure out what to do, because I couldn't find anyone else through Googling who had explained how to change it:

Go to **keyboard shortcuts** in **KDE settings** and search for **alt+up**. Find any program you can that uses it, **or** *any non-programmatic reservation*.  I actually found *two* reservations for **alt+up** *that weren't even doing anything* except preventing VS Code's keybindings from functioning properly.

Obviously, this should help with other keybinding collisions, too.
Remove those keybindings in KDE and they should immediately start working in VS Code like you'd expect - if it *doesn't* work, try and find any other programs with global keybindings that might be causing the conflict.

Answer (score -1):

I think Hans Passant has the right answer.  I am using VS2017 with CodeLens and ReSharper as well.  I do not have this same issue, but if I go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and type the shortcut in the "Press shortcut keys" box as Hans said, I have a large list of items.  I can then disable an individual item by typing the text in the drop down into the "Show commands containing" box, selecting it then removing the shortcut for that command.  Your issue truly sounds like a keyboard shortcut issue and I would be willing to bet there is some scrolling command that is bound to your Alt + Up Arrow and Alt + Down Arrow keys.

Comment: Believe me, I checked on this long before I posted this. In "Shortcut currently used by:" for "Alt+Up Arrow", I have Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp (Text Editor) and ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Item.MoveUp (Solution Explorer).  As I have said above, when I turn off CodeLens, the problem goes away. This leads me to believe that the problem is a bug with CodeLens.